# Setting a variable for a particular room in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a socket.io application. Now, for some needs I want create/set/get variables for a room. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but you have to *hardcode* it (keep the variables and assigning it by hand in an external object).
You can also take a look at socket.io-hotel module (https://github.com/gpestana/socket.io-hotel), which implements that functionality through

```
setPropertyRoom(roomID, key, val, clbk)
```